# Find the boundary of a function's Domain?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

$D=${$(x,y)\in R^2  : x^2+9y^2 \le 1$, $3x+9y^2 \le 1$}

1 ) find the boundary $\vartheta D$ of $D$ , and sketch D.
What shoud I do in order to find the boundary of a given domain as :

$D=${$(x,y)\in R^2   :  A \le n , B \le n' $}  (with A,B inequalities)

2 ) And how do I calculate the flux of the vector field $F(x,y,z) = z^2+y^2+x^2$ coming out of $\vartheta D$  ?

Comment: $3x+9y^2=1$ is a parabola (sideways) and $x^2+9y^2=1$ is an ellipse. Where do they intersect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$D$ looks like this:

[image]

It is the region bounded by the blue curve (on le the left) and the pink one (on the right). Both curves intersect in $(0,-1/3)$ and $(0,1/3)$. Therefore, you can write $D$ as follows:
$$
D=\{(x,y)\;|\; -\frac{1}{3} \le y \le \frac{1}{3}, -\sqrt{1-9y^2} \le x \le \frac{1-9y^2}{3} \}
$$

and for the boundary $\partial D$ 
$$
\partial D = \left\{(x,y)\;|\; x=-\sqrt{1-9y^2}, x\in [-1,0] \right\}\cup \left\{(x,y)\;|\; \frac{1-9y^2}{3}, x\in [0,\frac{1}{3}] \right\}
$$

Comment: Can you also help me calculate the Flux coming out of D (the second part of the question)

Comment: $F$ is not a vector field, as you have defined it. I would suggest posting this as a separate question.